# how to customise uiwebview cangoback only for hyperlinks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i need to use a uiwebview for multiple urls and  to cache the  history for some of them (webpage with hyperlink) and there i need cangoback value as yes but in other case some urls doesn't need this caching, Is there any way to check only the required urls (hyperlinked) and how to do that back navigation only for that? thanks in advace

my back navigation code

```
-(IBAction) backButtonClick
{
    if (webView.canGoBack )
    {
     [webView goBack];

    }
    else
    {
        [appDelegate popViewControllerFromNavController:self.navigationController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find out any answer to this question?